# Facebook Profile not linking to Groups I admin for

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I have a personal Facebook profile and now admin 2 NFP Facebook community groups.
Problem is not being able to post in the group as an admin (posts as me personally everytime) and no function to be able to 'switch or toggle between profiles'.
The 'pages you manage' screen is blank and does list the groups I manage.
I was granted full admin access in one group and the other group I created as sole admin myself.
I have troubleshooted multiple avenues already for a fix, without success.
Are there any FB gurus out there who can help with this please!??